# java path to file on server must double backslah

Tags: java, jfilechooser, backslash, unc, pathname

I have a Java GUI. The user selects with the JFileChooser Dialog a file including the path to the file. The path is displayed in a text box, e.g.

```
\\developDB\directory\subdirectory\file.info
```

When I access the file with an InputStream  using the path selected  by the user  (and displayed in the textbox) it does not find the file. Oops.

Now I double all backslashes in the text box. i.e.

```
\\developDB\\directory\\subdirectory\\file.info
```

and read again with the InputStream with the path from the textbox and now the file is found. Oops again.

You might think that the reason for this could be that the backslash must be escaped with another backslash but this is not the reason here. Internally Java doubles the backslash again for escape purpose.

Also when I try to access the file via web-browser, the backslashes must be doubled.

I was thinking that this may be related possibly to 2 causes:

- the JFileChooser is "eating" the backslashes for some reason. How could this be avoided?
- the JFileChooser is working fine but the server administrator of the server where the file is stored set-up some naming conventions for the path name. If so, how could I become aware of these standards in the Java program so that I can programmatically double the backslashes.

Hope I did not confuse you too much ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java standard IO library (java.io.FileInputStream, etc) you can use only forward slashes, Java will translate pending on the running platform.

Comment: @PetrMmm, is this also valid when the client platform is different from server platform?

Comment: Did you read this ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html